# How can I define the activity when the back-button is clicked in my App?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am nearly finished with my first Android App, but there is one thing that still bothers me: I have an activity with [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) fields and a "Start"-button that leads to a new Activity. When the user presses the back-button (the one thats on the phone), I get back to my first Activity. Can I change this and define a whole new Activity? A modified version of my first Activity?

Here is what I want to achieve:

First Activity - - > (start-button clicked)
- - > Second Activity - - > (back-button clicked)
- - > First Activity, modified.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "modified"?

Comment: I have a belonging xml-layout and I want this to appear at the start and when the back button is clicked. But I modify this layout programmatically in the beginning.. and when the back-button is clicked I want to modify the layout in a different way!

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`.

An example of this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android).

You will put your layout manipulation code as it were in the `onActivityResult` method in your first activity, and start the second activity using `startActivityForResult`.

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed() in your second activity and start your modified activity from there. Something like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     //start your activity here
    //make sure you remove the super call
}
```